# Referencing another sheet for data, for use with a duplicate-value checker in Excel using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have this spreadsheet that tells me if a name is not in one of two lists, by checking if it is there, and if it is not, then putting an X in the correct cell. I used: `=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,A:A),"","X")` in `B3`, and `=IF(COUNTIFS(G:G,A:A),"","X")` in `C3` and then auto filled down.

[image]

I am trying to have it so that I only have the first three columns in this spreadsheet, and the "Names1" and "Names2" being referenced from another sheet. ( to keep this discussion short and to the point, let's just discuss the names1 column, as the names2 column would be the same concept.)
 So, Names1 is just names from a large CSV file on another sheet (I copy pasted it for testing) that refreshes the cdv excel sheet with new data as data is added to the CSV file. I need to pull the names in Names1 from that csv excel sheet.

The csv excel file has a numbered list in the first column, and then the names in the second column. the table_array name is `csv` on the sheet.
This is what I am using, but I keep getting error codes no matter what I try:    `=VLOOKUP(A1,csv,2,FALSE)`
Also, I need it so that the original list checker function still works...
I am using Excel 2011 for Mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys! I've been stuck on this for waaay too long...

Comment: is the `table_array` a `named_range` or an `Excel_Table`? the vlookup is also failing because the numbered list is your left-most column, and you are trying to match names against numbers.

Comment: it is a named_range. I will try matching it to the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep this really simply by just writing.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Names1!B:B,A3),"","X")
=IF(COUNTIFS(Names2!B:B,A3),"","X")
```

where `Names1` and `Names2` are the sheet names for each list.

If you don't need to see separate lists, you can also combine them with this statement:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet5!B:B,A3)+COUNTIFS(Sheet4!B:B,A3),"","X")
```